# Beamer handout: removing a picture with message

Tags: beamer, graphics

When I produce the handout of a set of slides I want to remove a few (comic) pictures due to copyright reasons. In the handout, I want to get a frame with the same size of the picture with a centered message saying "Picture removed for copyright reasons".

I've come up with the following solution, using the package `calc`:

```
\only<beamer>{\includegraphics[width=<width>]{<filename>}}
\only<handout>{%
    \raisebox{\heightof{\includegraphics[width=<width>]{<filename>}}*\real{-0.5}}[0pt][0pt]%
        {\begin{minipage}{<width>}\centering Picture removed for copyright reasons\end{minipage}}
    \frame{\phantom{\includegraphics[width=<width>]{<filename>}}}%
 }
```

It works, and I will eventually turn it into a command, but I wonder:

1. Is there a way to simplify the code?
2. It's not clear to me why I have to lower the text instead of rising it. Is the baseline at the top of the included graphics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be simplified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\remimagebox}
\newcommand{\removedincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\remimagebox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[b][\ht\remimagebox][s]{\wd\remimagebox}{%
    \vfill
    \centering Picture removed for copyright reasons
    \vfill
    \vspace{0pt}
  }}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\removedincludegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly better implementation, that avoids overfilling the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}

\newsavebox{\remimagebox}
\newcommand{\removedincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\remimagebox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[b][\ht\remimagebox][s]{\wd\remimagebox}{%
    \vfill
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.9\wd\remimagebox,max height=\ht\remimagebox}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    Picture removed \\ for copyright \\ reasons
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \vfill
    \vspace{0pt}
  }}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\removedincludegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\removedincludegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}
\removedincludegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfetto, grazie! ;-)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I added an improved version

Comment: It seems that for the second solution, just adding `\usepackage{adjustbox}` to my document preamble generates a "! TeX capacity exceeded" error. Maybe it's a conflict with the other packages but I don't know how to track down the error source.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano That's a different question altogether: please, ask a new one providing a minimal failing example.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll first investigate a bit more, then if I really can't find the issue, I'll ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

The two solutions proposed here do not directly address the question but they do provide similar outcomes by hiding copyright-protected images. The first solution uses Beamer's `\includeonlylecture` command. Slides with copyright-protected images are designated as private. All other slides are public. Uncommenting the `\includeonlylecture{public}` line will include only public images. The private images will not be included.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\includeonlylecture{public}

\begin{document}

\lecture{public}{public}

\begin{frame}{This slide has a creative commons image.}

    The slide and information are always included.

    \vspace*{\baselineskip}

    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\end{frame}

% Hide the copyrighted slide.

\lecture{private}{private}

\begin{frame}{This slide has a copyright-protected image.}

    The slide does not contain any pubic information so the entire slide is hidden.

    \vspace*{\baselineskip}

    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\end{frame}

\lecture{public}{public}

\begin{frame}{This slide has a creative commons image.}

    The slide and image are always included.

    \vspace*{\baselineskip}

    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This example uses Beamer's `\alt` command to remove copyrighted images. Change which `\documentclass` is used. The `[handout]` form will remove the copyrighted images.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

%Puts the copyright restriction in a \parbox as wide as the image.
\newcommand\copyrighted[2]{%
    \alt<handout>{%
        \parbox{#1}{\centering Image removed for copyright reasons.}}% Handout
        {\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}%Non-handout
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{This slide has a creative commons image.}

    The image is always available.

    \vspace*{\baselineskip}

    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This slide has a copyright-protected image.}

    Public information with a copyright-protected image.

    \vspace*{\baselineskip}

    \alt<handout>{Image removed for copyright reasons.} 
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This slide also has a copyright-protected image.}

    Same information but in macro form. 

    \vspace*{\baselineskip}

    \copyrighted{3cm}{example-image}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]